# Unable to create new Documents in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently switched to Firestore in one of my iOS apps. I am trying to store some settings in the "settings" collection.

I have the following code:

```
let data = FSSettings().store() // returns [String : Any]

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let document = db.collection("settings").document(uid) // I tried this

document.setData(data)
{
   error in
   Swift.print(error?.localizedDescription)
}

// And this..
db.collection("settings").addDocument(data: data)
{
    error in
    Swift.print(error?.localizedDescription)
}
```

According to the Firestore documentation, this would create the document (and also the collection). But the document is not being created. I have set a breakpoint at the print() line, but this is also never being called.

Here are my rules in Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This should also work, because I am logged in. I also tried a different method using a transaction:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let document = db.collection("settings").document(uid)

db.runTransaction(
{
   transaction, errorPointer in

   transaction.updateData(data, forDocument: document)
})
{
   // Completion
   object, error in
   if let error = error
   {
       Swift.print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

When running this statement, the following line is printed:

```
Transaction failed all retries.
```

What am I missing? My app runs on iOS 12.0 and is using the latest Firebase/Firestore version (CocoaPods).

When I create the document manually, I can change the values without any problems, it is only the creation that fails.

Comment: Your first section of code works perfectly for me. I set up two local vars *let data = ["name": "Test"]* and *let uid = "uid_0"* made no other changes and ran the code. It created a *settings* collection and document *uid_0* with *name: uid_0*. So my guess is *let data = FSSettings().store()* is returning nil or there's a rules issue or maybe you're not authenticated*

Comment: Hello, the store() method returns 6 key/value pairs, so the data is not empty. I changed the security rule to allow everything and it still does not work. The most confusing part is that the method does not even return an error. If it was a security issue, I would expect that at least an error is returned.

Comment: Agreed but I literally copy and pasted your code into an app, made the two changes I mentioned and ran it and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Firestore initialization takes some time. The settings are created right at the start of the app, so the Firestore was not initialized yet. Running the code above with a slight delay of 2 seconds works fine.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The code in my app runs immediately in the very first viewDidLoad function in the first viewController. Maybe is your internet connection. I would dig a bit deeper as that's a bit suspect. The only Firestore initialization is within the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions functions and should be *FirebaseApp.configure()*

Comment: The problem was, that it was test code that was also run in applicationDidFinishLaunching (pretty much right after the call to FirebaseApp.configure()).